# Posting JSON object through WinJS.XHR

Tags: xmlhttprequest, winjs

I'm having abit of problems posting data from WinJS.xhr to a PHP script.
"obj" is a stringified JSON object

```
WinJS.xhr({
            type: "POST",
            url: dataUrl,
            headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
            data: obj,
        })
```

However the $_POST variable is always empty.

I've tried changing content-types, and escaping the object but no luck :(

Comment: If it's JSON, why are you sending it as `x-www-form-urlencoded`? Why not `application/json`?

Comment: @WiredPrairie, tried using application/json same thing, came across a post with a guy who had the same problem where this fixed it. I wasnt so lucky tho.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a soloution.

Incase anyone has the same problem i got it working by removing headers from the xhr, and getting the post data @ server side with this code:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = (array) json_decode($data);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your content-type when posting json should typically be application/json

Secondly make sure you 'stringify' your json object.

Based on: [Post JSON data to web services in Windows 8](http://dkdevelopment.net/2012/04/27/post-json-data-to-web-services-in-windows-8/)

```
WinJS.xhr({
            type: "post",
            url: dataUrl,
            headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
            data: JSON.stringify(obj)
        })
```