# What is the correct syntax for winjs.xhr data

Tags: windows-8.1, winjs

I tried to use winjs.xhr to POST some data to a URL with no success. I got it working by essentially doing the same thing with XMLHttpRequest. This just doesn't feel right, as winjs.xhr, I thought, wraps XMLHttpRequest anyway. Can anyone explain how I do this in winjs.xhr?

## Not working winjs.xhr code

Passing everything in as a URL encoded string

```
var url = "http://localhost/paramecho.php";

var targetUri = "http://localhost/paramecho.php";
var formParams = "username=foo&password=bar" //prefixing with a '?' makes no difference
//ends up with same response passing an object(below) or string (above)
//var formObj = {username: "foo", password: "bar"} 

WinJS.xhr({
    type: "post",
    url: targetUri,
    data: formParams

}).then(function (xhr) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
});
```

I end up with my receiving PHP file getting none of the parameters, as though I'd sent no data in the first place.

I tried a few things but the code above is the simplest example. If I was to pass an object into the data parameter it behaves the same way (commented out). I've used a FormData object as well as a plain JSON object.

I changed my app manifest to have the correct network capabilities - and the working example below was done in the same app, so I'm confident it's not capability-related.

## Working version using XMLHttpRequest

```
var username = "foo";
var password = "bar";
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
try {
    request.open("POST", "http://localhost/paramecho.php", false);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send("username=" + encodeURIComponent(username) + "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(password));
    console.log(request.responseText);
} catch (e) {
    console.log("networkError " + e.message + "   " + e.description);
}
```

And this successfully calls my PHP server-side function, with the parameters I expected.

So, the question is...how do I achieve what I have working in XMLHttpRequest with winjs.xhr? It feels like winjs.xhr the way this is supposed to work (I'm a newbie at Windows 8 app development so I'm happy to be corrected)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Posting JSON object trough WinJS.XHR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007540/posting-json-object-trough-winjs-xhr)

Comment: It's just a thin wrapper. It doesn't set the header for content type automatically. You'll see in the working example that you added the header, but in the WinJs version, you did not.

Answer (score 1):

You're completely right WiredPrairie. Passing in the header is all that is needed - I think I'd assumed that was the default for a post.

Working version:

```
WinJS.xhr({
    type: "post",
    url: targetUri,
    data: formParams,
    headers: {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
}).then(function (xhr) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
});
```